# "No appropriate default constructor available" in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I'm trying to use C++11 initializers to avoid writing unnecessary default constructors.  However, I get the error "no appropriate default constructor available", and don't understand why.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct Foo
{
   double fieldA { 0.0 }; // Initializer
   short  fieldB { 0   }; // Initializer
   SomeObj myObj;         // Use default ctor of SomeObj

   // Foo() = default; // this line doesn't help!

   Foo(const SourceData& src)
   {            // Error: No Appropriate Default Ctor!
        fieldA = src.GetFieldA();
        fieldB = src.GetFieldB();
        myObj  = src.GetObject();
   }
};
```

I don't see any reason that compiler generated default constructor wouldn't be available and wouldn't work.  Even when I "encourage" the compiler to generate a default constructor, I still get the same message.

If I actually write out a default-ctor, then it does work.  But that defeats the purpose of using initializers in place of a constructor, right?

---

**Edit** Some have suggested the problem is with SomeObj and its constructor.
SomeObj is also a P.O.D. class, using just initializers to set its data.

Comment: I think this is talking about the constructor for `SomeObj`. Does that have a default constructor?

Comment: What compiler do you use?
I think TartanLlama is correct

Comment: You need to post the whole code of SomeObj.

Comment: @Puppy:  (currently working on a short, reproducible example.  Will post it when I can)

Comment: If SomeObj has any constructor defined, then I believe you need to specify that the default constructor is default.  You should not need to specify that if there are no constructors defined.

Comment: Someone voted to close because they think this isn't programming related?   Are they daft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typically just initialize the objects in the initializer list instead of default-constructing them and then assigning to them.

However, there's no reason why the compiler should accept a user-written empty default constructor over a defaulted one.

The most likely explanation is that `SomeObj` has no default constructor, or possibly that it is `explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is referring to the default constructor of `SomeObj` rather than `Foo`. If you don't initialize your member data in the initialization list, they'll be default-constructed before your constructor body is entered. You probably want to do this:

```
Foo(const SourceData& src) :
    fieldA {src.GetFieldA()}, fieldB {src.GetFieldB()}, myObj {src.GetObject()}
{ }
```